Trying to ssh to server but error in libcrypto
i tried ssh into server as always:
$ ssh host

but got this error message.
Load key "/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519": error in libcrypto

the private key files format, was a space instead of new lines.
whats the problem?

The ssh key wasn't formatted correctly. following the standard format, ie new lines instead of spaces, solved the issue.
